# Check word frequency of text file based on word list

Tags: python, nlp

I met an issue with checking the word frequency.

I have a downloaded 10-K, which looks like this:

> In particular, the virtual economies that we have established in many
> of our games are subject to abuse, exploitation and other forms of
> fraudulent activity that can negatively impact our
> business. Virtual economies involve the use of virtual currency
> and/or virtual assets that can be used or redeemed by a player within
> a particular game or service. The abuse or exploitation of our virtual
> economies include the illegitimate generation and sale of virtual
> items in black markets. Our online services have been impacted by
> in-game exploits and the use of automated processes to generate
> virtual currency illegitimately, and such activity may continue. 
> These kinds of activities and the steps that we take to address these
> issues may result in a loss of anticipated revenue, interfere with
> players’ enjoyment of a balanced game environment and cause
> reputational harm.
> Our
> business could be adversely affected if our consumer protection, data
> privacy and security practices are not adequate, or perceived as being
> inadequate, to prevent data breaches, or by the application of
> consumer protection and data privacy and security laws generally.

My coding is:

```
counter = {}
path=r'C:\test\QTR2\712515\0000712515-17-000035.txt'
word=['virtual currency','virtual currencies','Bitcoin','Litecoin','dogecoin','Etherrum']
doc = re.findall('\w+', open(path).read().lower())
for i in doc:
    if i in word:
        counter[i]= + 1
counter
```

However, the result is empty. The text has "virtual currency". Could anyone please help me check which part of the coding went wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you're not finding anything. You will never match `Bitcoin` `Litecoin` or `Etherrum`  to a lowercase string and you will never match `virtual currency` or `virtual currencies` to single word strings. Doesn't leave much — you are counting `dogecoin` and nothing else. To debug this, forget about the text file and put in a small string you _know_ should match. This will also help asking questions because you can give a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What should I do to match the "virtual currency"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re

counter = {}
path = 'test.txt'
words = ['virtual currency', 'virtual currencies', 'bitcoin', 'litecoin', 'dogecoin', 'ethereum']

doc = open(path).read().lower()

for word in words:
    counter[word] = doc.count(word)

print(counter)
```

Result:

```
{'virtual currency': 2, 'virtual currencies': 0, 'bitcoin': 0, 'litecoin': 0, 'dogecoin': 0, 'ethereum': 0}
```